# Calculating R-squared (coefficient of determination) from WLS linear regression with zero intercept

Tags: linear-model, regression-coefficients, r-squared, weighted-regression, intercept

I need to calculate the R^2  for a weighted least squares (WLS) regression model which is also a regression through the origin (RTO). I'd like to use it for comparing the quality of the fits for the dataset I got by using different weighting methods. I found the formula of computing R^2 in case of RTO in several publications:
[image]

The problem is I get different results using the 2 forms of the equation, in other words, the equation [image]

does not stand in my case. I guess it is because of the WLS regression because when I use OLS with RTO for the dataset, the equation is correct. Unfortunately, I could not find any publications about calculating R^2 for WLS combined with RTO.
I figured out that the equation that my statistical computing program uses for WLS combined with RTO is:

[image]

Can someone please explain the theoretical justification behind this equation (or suggest a better formula to use for the problem)?

Comment: When it comes to generalizing familiar ideas to exotic settings, I think an important consideration is what you liked about the familiar setting that makes you want to generalize the idea in the first place. For instance, you could compare on MSE or MAE. What is it about $R^2$ that makes you interested in generalizing it? For me, I like the idea of comparing to a naïve baseline of always predicting the conditional mean to be the marginal mean, and I can interpret this. What meaning do you want from your calculation? +1 for the interesting question, but I believe this is worth pondering.